# Sklearn - Override random_state=None by default

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, parameter

Many scikit-learn and pandas objects/functions use `random_state=None` as a default parameter. How can it be overridden to `random_state=100` by default for all objects without manually editing the `random_state` for each object?

```
make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=3, cluster_std=1.0, 
           center_box=(-10.0, 10.0), shuffle=True, random_state=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

For scikit-learn can set `np.random.seed(1)`, for example, and as long as nothing in your script is modifying the seed nondeterministically then you should get reproducible results.

This is described in the scikit-learn FAQ under [How do I set a `random_state` for an entire execution?](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution)

However, I don't believe it is possible to do the same thing for pandas. See [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13143) for discussion.